# how to merge arrays inside the array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, array-merge

I want to merge the arrays inside the array so that i can get a single array having all data in laravel

```
[
    [
        {
            "view_id": 1,
            "meta_detail_id": 1
        },
        {
            "view_id": 2,
            "meta_detail_id": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "view_id": 7,
            "meta_detail_id": 4
        }
    ]
]
```

this is `$data` array having two array inside it and expected result is

```
[
    {
        "view_id": 1,
        "meta_detail_id": 1
    },
    {
        "view_id": 2,
        "meta_detail_id": 1
    },
    {
        "view_id": 7,
        "meta_detail_id": 4
    }
]
```

I have tried with array_merge but got same result

```
$merged = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array($data));
$merged=array_merge(...array($data));
return $merged;
```

Comment: You can loop through the main array and create a new array from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

laravel collection example.

```
collect($array)->flatten(1);
```